# Hidding user informations due to their privacy

Tags: php, mysql, web

Im building web app which include user authentification, so every user will have profile with personal data. Data will be stored in db, but due to their privacy users can choose which of their informations will be displayed to public visitors. Let say someone want to hide his phone number from others, so he will go to account setings and choose "hide" option. But I cant figure out how to make it with db and rest of app.
Any guidance or reference will be helpfull. Thanks

Comment: Too little information provided to answer this question. And even then, it might be too broad.

Comment: Please visit [**How do I ask a good question?**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Check a certain column each time a profile is loaded what it can and can't show according to what it says in the database?

Comment: What are you having issues with, how to store it or how to display/not display it?

Answer (score 0):

Make your table look like something like this. This means that `John` and `Laura` have different privacy settings than `Jane` and `sam`.

```
+-------+------------+------------+--------+
| user  |   phone    |  address   | hidden |
+-------+------------+------------+--------+
| john  | 2025550165 | example 1  |      1 |
| jane  | 2026118043 | example 2  |      0 |
| sam   | 2026682607 | example 3  |      0 |
| laura | 2026688273 | example 4  |      1 |
+-------+------------+------------+--------+
```

To use this, the `SQL` would be something like: `SELECT user, phone, address from table where hidden = 0`

which would return only `jane` and `sam`.

Does this help at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can create some table like **user_settings** where user can set what fields should not be visible to public